# Should all agile epics be titled in sentences?

Tags: agile, scrum, youtrack, agile-project-management, agile-processes

I'm reorganizing my agile board on youtrack and am trying to conform to the industry best practices however I would much rather call an epic

**"User Profile"**

as opposed to

**"A users can view their own and other users information and content on their user profile"**

if I can get away with it.

I'm going to be applying for jobs soon so theres a chance someone might look at what I've done and I just want to make sure I don't look bad because of something like this.

To further clarify how I view each "Type" of issue (to make sure I'm understanding them correctly)

Epic - User Profile (brief description)

Feature - User Feed (detailed description)

Task - A user may like items in the feed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The title of an epic should be 'fit for purpose'. What that purpose is depends on how you are using them.

For example, say you were the only person who had visibility of the epics. In that case the epic title should be something that made sense to you. If, however, the epic was visible widely across business users then it would make sense to use an epic title that means the most to them.

There isn't really a 'best practice' when it comes to this kind of thing as agile approaches vary so much. Really it is about finding a solution that works well for your particular organisation and if it doesn't work well, adapting it to be better.

I would suggest the only situation you absolutely want to avoid is having epic titles that are meaningful to the delivery team, but not understood by the business users.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing the epic stories, probably you don't have the same clarity level on what the customer really want.
So the epic title might be "User Profile" while later on when you start creating the user stories; the user story title "As user I want to be able to update my profile so that I can add avatar".

Answer (score -1):

There is really no logical difference between an epic and a story; the distinction is one of scale. In fact, it is often the case that a story *becomes* an epic when the team estimates it to be relatively large.

Answer (score -1):

We find it really easier to go through the product backlog items, specially when we are trying to rank them by  showing a title which sum-up the main purpose behind the user story and if more details is needed then we dig into it to check the whole user story with it is acceptance criteria.